# IIS7 - 2 different site with same ip and same port number

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis, iis-7

in IIS7 , i want to create 2 website

in 2 website 1 - website will pointing to 2 domainnames
and other will potinnting to 1 domain name

but 2 created website will use port number **80**

[image]
[image]

**Question is : Can i create 2 different site : EBS and RSS using same ip address and port 80?**

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's very common to share IP's and Port's, so by putting in the hostname it will know to distinguish the 2 sites. You've not mentioned any issues/errors. Just make sure the dns name it gets presented with is the same as your hostnames. Some firewalls allow you to change these, else it will get the external name.

Comment: my problem is , i want to make sure, for example, here in youtube comments : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFshi2SPHxM

Comment: We do it all the time. I don't know what your dns is or what you have in front of your servers but as long as your hostnames are all the same then you will be OK. Have you tested this in a dev environment??

Comment: No, i did not, but many of us saying, you cannot use same port :(

Comment: it is pretty confusing to me :(

Comment: SSL / HTTPS is the only weird one if your SSL cert needs a dedicated IP

Comment: Maybe put IIS on a test machine, fake some DNS entries and then create your sites - then you can see if it will work in your specific environment

Comment: These are some IIS Sites on the subject
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46681/discussion-between-vir-and-asg)

Comment: The screenshot you posted is a valid configuration. As long as your host names are unique then you're good.